# any OpenRasta reference applications or examples?

Tags: openrasta

I'm looking for projects, reference apps, examples, so on, for reference, with code, of course. Not simple helloworlds, do you know any? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta/wiki

and

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta/wiki/Building-Your-First-OpenRasta-Website